# Check 2 fields in a select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table named 'members'.

**MEMBERS |** member_id, username, email, password, domain_name

email field couldn't be `NULL` but domain_name could be.

Here I want to make a `SELECT` Query to get username and email or domain_name. If domain_name exist for a particular member_id then I don't need to select email. If not I need to get email.

This is my query I am using at this time. But It select both email and domain.

```
SELECT email, username, domain_name 
FROM members
ORDER BY username DESC;
```

Can anybody help me to update this select query?
Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query

Comment: I don't know your scenario but I would advise to use logic in your server side code.

Comment: @Samosa Yes this logic can be use in server side code. But what is different if I use this logic in sql query?

Comment: There are many reasons :-

Please read..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704106/business-logic-in-php-or-mysql
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449072/doing-calculations-in-mysql-vs-php

Comment: IMHO fickle business logic should be done via Server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
SELECT 
  username,
  CASE
    WHEN domain_name IS NULL 
    THEN email 
    ELSE domain_name 
  END your_alias 
FROM
  members 
ORDER BY username DESC ;
```

`your_alias` could be any name you want to specify as a column it can be email or domain_name

Comment: People usually have trouble this, so I'll throw out a helper, `your_alias` is actually the name of the column that you will use when you iterate this query. `$row['your_alias']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **IF** function in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT `username`, 
IF(`domain_name` IS NULL ,`email`, `domain_name`) as `email_or_domain` 
FROM `members`
```

The syntax of the MySQL IF function is:

> IF(expr,if_true_expr,if_false_expr)